# Upload img throws web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to insert a image to perstashop using their webservice, but I'm not being able to make it work. 
I have to do it with Java and I have only found one example with PHP. Could anyone help me?
Thank you

```
    private void addImg(String imgURL, int productId) throws Exception {

    URL imgUrl = new URL(imgURL);
    InputStream is = imgUrl.openStream();

    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];
    while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }
    buffer.flush();

    String completeUrlString = URLSTRING + "/api/images/products/" + String.valueOf(productId);
    URL completeUrl = new URL(completeUrlString);
    con = connectionWebService.connection(completeUrl);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( con.getOutputStream() );
    writer.write (Arrays.toString(buffer.toByteArray()));
    connectionWebService.readServer();
}
```

Connection to web service:

```
final HttpURLConnection connection (URL url) throws IOException {  
    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String userpass = "P9ZAAG9JVSM7DU455XP36TZRWYV6JEEA";
    new Base64();
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encode(userpass.getBytes());
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
    con.setReadTimeout(20000);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "text/xml" );
    return con;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the error that you're getting when you try to upload? Can you also provide a link to the documentation for the API you're trying to upload to? My initial assumption is that it's expecting a `mutlipart/form-data` POST request, which is not what you're doing. I'd suggest looking at Http Client https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html rather than using Java's URL library.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost/prestashop/api/images/products/25. I am not using http client of Apache. I am using HttpURLConnection of java.

Comment: And the documentation? How is it expecting you to upload the file?

Comment: Making post to URL and post img in array of bytes